# IOException Error on Putting Uri Source In Media Player (setDataSource)

Tags: android-mediaplayer, ioexception, file-type

Getting an IOException Error While Putting Uri Source Into An Object Of MediaPlayer Using setDataSource. Trying To Get Uri Of A Song From Mobile Using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

**onActivityResult**

```
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 10){
                Uri uriSound=data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It Came Here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                play_sound(uriSound);
            }
        }
```

**play_sound**

```
private void play_sound( Uri uri) {


             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It Came Here 2" + uri,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

            try {

                mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error 3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error 4",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

I Used Toast To Check Where Is Error .

Getting Error In "IOException e" I Dont Know What Is It On Googling It All I Get Is That It Is SOme Kind Of  " File Format" Issue Of Selected File.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! By Just Adding One Line In Play Sound

```
 mP.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Play_Sound(Uri uri) :

```
private void Play_Sound(Uri uri)
        {
            MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might 1 not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might 2 not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might 3 not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might 4 not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mPlayer.start();
        }
```